# htacces, some rewrited url give me error 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, debian, wamp

i have a problem with a htaccess file in Debian 8 (it works perfectly and everything is ok in my wamp server):

```
RewriteBase /

#Remove trailing slash from url
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule  ^action/(.*)$ action.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

in Debian url like `/index.php?path=login` become correctly `/login` and everything is ok, but this doesn't work with url like `index.php?path=index`: the rewrited url `/index` show me error 404.
The same thing happen with rule for `action/` (that doesn't work with anything).
Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]` You don't need to escape your `/` in .htaccess ... and `RewriteRule` doesn't match against the query string anyway so `\?.*` would never match anything. A simple `^(.*)/?$` would do the trick to remove the trailing slash... not that it makes any odds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Remove trailing slash from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^action/(.*)$ action.php?action=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to next `RewriteRule`.